# Access to LWC child component by key

Tags: lightning-web-components

Let's say I have a code like this:

```
<template for:each={items} for:item="item">
    <c-child-comp key={item.key}> </c-child-comp>
</template>
```

Is there any way to access a single child component using key value and use @api method for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the key is used only by the framework/runtime. If you want something you can use, you can assign it a custom data attribute:

```
<c-child-comp key={item.key} data-key={item.key}>
</c-child-comp>
```

Which you can then access:

```
this.template.querySelector(`[data-key="some-key"]`)
```

This works even if the component does not define a data key (e.g. `@api dataKey`).

Comment: That's perfect, thank you

Comment: Just an addendum that helped me.  To access this from within the child component itself, you can access it from this.template.host.dataset:  let key = this.template.host.dataset.key;

Comment: @drakored Interesting. I learnt something. I'd still recommend using a dataset attribute, as that's what it's there for, but nice to know it is actually accessible.